# Goroutines, Channels, WaitGroups, and select (just trying to understand)

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am not necessarily trying to accomplish something specific, more just understand how goroutines, channels, waitgroups, and select (on channels) plays together.  I am writing a simple program that loops through an slice of URLs, fetches the URL, then basically just ends.  The simple idea is that I want all of the fetches to occur and return, send their data over channels, and then end once all fetches have occurred.  I am almost there, and I know I am missing something in my select that will end the loop, something to say "hey the waitgroup is empty now", but I am unsure how to best do that.  Mind taking a look and clearing it up for me?  Right now everything runs just fine, it just doesn't terminate, so clearly I am missing something and/or not understanding how some of these components should work together.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "https://www.google.com1",
    "https://www.gentoo.org",
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

// simple struct to store fetching
type urlObject struct {
    url     string
    success bool
    body    string
}

func getPage(url string, channelMain chan urlObject, channelError chan error) {

    // increment waitgroup, defer decrementing
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("fetching " + url)

    // create a urlObject
    uO := urlObject{
        url:     url,
        success: false,
    }

    // get URL
    response, getError := http.Get(url)

    // close response later on
    if response != nil {
        defer response.Body.Close()
    }

    // send error over error channel if one occurs
    if getError != nil {
        channelError <- getError
        return
    }

    // convert body to []byte
    body, conversionError := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    // convert []byte to string
    bodyString := string(body)

    // if a conversion error happens send it over the error channel
    if conversionError != nil {
        channelError <- conversionError
    } else {
        // if not send a urlObject over the main channel
        uO.success = true
        uO.body = bodyString
        channelMain <- uO
    }

}

func main() {

    var channelMain = make(chan urlObject)
    var channelError = make(chan error)

    for _, v := range urls {
        go getPage(v, channelMain, channelError)
    }

    // wait on goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()

    for {
        select {
        case uO := <-channelMain:
            fmt.Println("completed " + uO.url)
        case err := <-channelError:
            fmt.Println("error: " + err.Error())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The main thread needs to wait for goroutines to finish, so clearly `wg.Add(1)` is misplaced in your attempt.

Comment: Thanks @Inian! Where should it be?

Comment: Typically the call to `Add` is immediately *before* starting the goroutine that will end up calling `Done`. This ensures that the `Add` call happens before the `Wait` call, which is not ensured if you call it inside the goroutine.

Comment: Got it! It does the same thing if I move the `Add(1)` to the loop.

Comment: Note that you can make a tiny optimization: you know that `for ... range urls` is going to run `len(urls)` times. If it calls `wg.Add(1)` each time inside the loop, you can make it read `wg.Add(len(urls))` once above the loop. The only minor flaw in this is that if the loop ever changes so that it doesn't actually call `go getPage` once per URL, you'll have to move the `wg.Add` back into the loop or otherwise modify the `len(urls)` argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the following changes:

- As people have mentioned, you probably want to call `wg.Add(1)` in the main function, before calling your goroutine. That way you KNOW it occurs before the `defer wg.Done()` call.
- Your channel reads will block, unless you can figure out a way to either close the channels in your goroutines, or make them buffered. Probably the easiest way is to make them buffered, e.g., `var channelMain = make(chan urlObject, len(urls))`
- The `break` in your select statement is going to only exit the select, not the containing `for` loop. You can label the for loop and break to that, or use some sort of conditional variable.

Playground link to working version:  https://play.golang.org/p/WH1fm2MhP-L

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "https://www.google.com1",
    "https://www.gentoo.org",
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

// simple struct to store fetching
type urlObject struct {
    url     string
    success bool
    body    string
}

func getPage(url string, channelMain chan urlObject, channelError chan error) {

    // increment waitgroup, defer decrementing
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("fetching " + url)

    // create a urlObject
    uO := urlObject{
        url:     url,
        success: false,
    }

    // get URL
    response, getError := http.Get(url)

    // close response later on
    if response != nil {
        defer response.Body.Close()
    }

    // send error over error channel if one occurs
    if getError != nil {
        channelError <- getError
        return
    }

    // convert body to []byte
    body, conversionError := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    // convert []byte to string
    bodyString := string(body)

    // if a conversion error happens send it over the error channel
    if conversionError != nil {
        channelError <- conversionError
    } else {
        // if not send a urlObject over the main channel
        uO.success = true
        uO.body = bodyString
        channelMain <- uO
    }

}

func main() {

    var channelMain = make(chan urlObject, len(urls))
    var channelError = make(chan error, len(urls))

    for _, v := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go getPage(v, channelMain, channelError)
    }

    // wait on goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()

    for done := false; !done; {
        select {
        case uO := <-channelMain:
            fmt.Println("completed " + uO.url)
        case err := <-channelError:
            fmt.Println("error: " + err.Error())
        default:
            done = true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!